# compare and set operation Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am studying multithreading in java.

I have a class

```
public class CASCount<T> {
    private final AtomicReference<Integer> count = new AtomicReference<>(0);
    
    public int get() {
        return count.get();
    }
}
```

and there is a increment method :

```
    public void increment() {
        int t;
        do {
            t = count.get();
        }
        while (!count.compareAndSet(t, t + 1));
    }
```

which could be simplified like this:

```
    public void increment() {
        int t;
        while (!count.compareAndSet(t = count.get(), t + 1));
    }
```

or like this:

```
public void increment() {
        while (!count.compareAndSet(count.get(), count.get() +1));
    }
```

I have been told that I couldn't because other threads could change the data inside the method.
But, as I know, Compare and Set(CAS) is an atomic operation, and if the first get() returns 0 and the second get() returns 1, the CAS operation cannot change the counter, because if get() returns 1, it means the data has already changed.

My question is why I can not do the above operations if CAS is atomic, and why it is not advisable to do so?

Comment: Do not use `AtomicReference<Integer>`. Use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)! It has an [`incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) method.

Comment: (I'm not an expert in concurrency) I think you are right that this makes no difference on functionality, but since `get` "has the memory effects of reading a volatile variable", there might be some performance impacts of calling it twice (?) Also, styles matter too. All the `compareAndSet` code I've seen are in a form similar to the `getAndTransform` shown on [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html#package.description). Writing your code the same way makes it a lot more easily understandable. People are pattern spotters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rewrite is correct.  This version performs the same operations in the same order as in the original one.  Since the codes are equivalent, and the original is correct, so is the rewrite.

The second rewrite requires deeper analysis.  In the following T1, T2, T3 and so on denote distinct threads.  (I am ignoring the boxing and unboxing that goes on, because I am pretty sure that it makes no difference to the analysis.)

Let us start with the case where threads only call the `increment` method; i.e. the counter only increases.  If a T1 manages to increment the counter while T1 is calling `increment` between the first `get()` call and before the `compareAndSet()` call, then `compareAndSet(i1, i2)` will (always) see that the `i1` value is different to current value.  It will therefore NOT perform the "set".  The fact that the second `get()` call may return a different value to the first one is moot.  The 2nd rewrite is correct in this case.

But what if there is also a `decrement` method coded like this:

```
public void decrement() {
    int t;
    while (!count.compareAndSet(count.get(), count.get() - 1));
}
```

And suppose that T1 and T2 call `increment` and T3 calls `decrement` at the same time with the following interleaving of operations

```
T1:  getCount() -> 0
T2:  getCount() -> 0, getCount() -> 0, compareAndSet(0, 0 + 1) -> true, 1
T1:  getCount() -> 1,
T3:  getCount() -> 1, getCount() -> 1, compareAndSet(1, 1 - 1) -> true, 0
T1:  compareAndSet(0, 1 + 1) -> true, 2
```

and we have lost the effect of T3's decrement!

In other words, the second rewrite is **incorrect** if we cannot assume that the value counter is monotonically increasing.

---

> My question is why I can not do the above operations if CAS is atomic.

One of the rewrites is incorrect in some use-cases; see above

> and why it is not advisable to do so?

Three reasons:

1. If it isn't broken, don't fix it.
2. If you rewrite a well-known concurrent algorithm, the onus is really on you to **prove** that the rewrite is correct.  And proving correctness is typically harder than proving incorrectness (like I just did above).
3. In this case, you call `getCount()` twice as many times to save a local variable.  The extra calls are a performance hit.  And since the time interval between the (first) `get` call and the `compareAndSet` is larger, the probability of looping increases.